# Update pricing table with new value and field to record date

Tags: mysql

I am managing an eCommerce database that has Amazon sales data and am still learning MySQL.  I am going to create a new pricing table, but am not 100% I am doing this the best way and want advice.

The table data I get from Amazon includes ASIN (Amazon's SKU that is unique to each product) and the price.  There are some other pieces of data, but those are the most important.  I want to add two pieces of info that I think make this table easier to maintain.  One is a created date field that is when I add a new ASIN that is not already there.  The second is an update date field showing the date when an ASIN price is updated to a newer price.  By doing this I do not have historical pricing detail, but I don't think I would need it.

Question #1: I think I want this line in the create statement for create date field:

```
create_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Correct?

Question #2: How would I update this table so it does not add a new record for an existing ASIN, but instead updates to the new price and changes the update_date value to the timestamp when that update was made?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the update_date field as

```
update_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and update the record simply as

```
UPDATE sales_table SET price = 123 WHERE id = 4
```

and the update_date column will change to reflect the new update timestamp.